# Angular 5 form duplicates input value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a simple form:

```
this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  query: [ null, [Validators.required] ]
});
```

When user paste something into the input I reformat values using regex and update the form.

```
onPaste(event) {
    const formattedQuery = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
      .split(/,?[\r\n\t]+\s?/)
      .join(', ')
      .replace(/,\s?$/g, '');

    this.searchForm.get('query').setValue(formattedQuery);
    // this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
```

But when I paste something, for example

```
325435956
325435956
```

It duplicate it and as a result I see `325435956, 325435956 325435956 325435956` but I expect to see `325435956, 325435956`. Where is my mistake and how to fix that?

Working example you can find here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cp9yhx?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: have this line `this.searchForm.setValue({value:''})` in the `onPaste` method and try once. This will clear the form value whenever we are pasting, I guess the value is retained in the object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you handle the paste function, the default behavior is left unchanged.

So, it first handles the method and prints out the expected values. And then pastes the values as is.

You should prevent the default behavior.

```
onPaste(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //rest of the method as it is right now
}
```

Fixed example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7orqb9?file=app/hello.component.ts